# Sync apps from computer to iPhone using iTunes

Tags: iphone, data-synchronization

I am unable to transfer apps from my computer to iPhone 5 running 6.0.1. Whenever I click on the `Install` button the button changes to `Will Install`.

Similarly, as soon as I click on the `Sync` button. synchronization terminates without any error at the step `Determining apps to sync`.

Any ideas on how I can fix this?

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like you might need to do a factory reset on the phone (AFTER DOING A BACKUP!).

Best to backup to your computer instead of to iCloud, since there are some things that are not backed up to iCloud.

Alternatively, just used the "purchased -> not on this phone" feature in the app store on the device. That will also let you install any app.